# How to refresh a form that is Data Bound in C#?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, data-binding, refresh

I have a list box that is data bound to a database and shows firstNames, I have a button that opens a new form and allows the user to edit said firstNames and then saves the changes back to the database(which works fine). My question is how do I update or refresh the list box in the first form, so that is shows the changes made(as of right now I have to close the application and reboot it to show changes made)?

Note:
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and created the forms using Windows Forms.

Comment: ASP.NET?  Winforms?  WPF?  What are you using?

Comment: @Kyle Trauberman - Windows Forms

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to reload data from a database into databinding source. If source does not implement [IBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx), you need manually refresh component:

```
// BindingContext - the property of ContainerControl (Form or UserControl)
var currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[listBox.DataSource, listBox.DataMember];
currencyManager.Refresh();
```

Comment: Okay, I tried this and I am getting this error "DataMember property "tblHorse" cannot be found on the DataSource."

this is what I changed it to
// BindingContext - the property of ContainerControl (Form or UserControl)
   var currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[lstHorseNames.DataSource,tblHorseBindingSource.DataMember];currencyManager.Refresh();

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but....

"However, you can force the combo box to be updated by calling the SuspendBinding and ResumeBinding methods on the instance of the BindingContext class to which the control is bound."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984341%28VS.71%29.aspx

(It should be the same for a ListBox)

Answer (score 0):

Write Select query in Form_Load and call after where ever you need to refresh your form like:

```
form_load(Object sender,Event_args e)
{
    select Query to display on Loading form
}

add_click(Object sender,Event_args e)
{
    form_load(sender,e)
}
```